# Is there any web browser engine for .net which can give back the response cookies with its path?

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, webbrowser-control

I need a web browser engine for using in my C# application (same as 'WebBrowser' of .Net). I need an engine which can give me back a cookie collection per request but with its full details such as path/domain etc... 
I tried many browser engines but couldn't managed to find one that can give me back this trivial thing I need, actually, the 'WebBrowser' of .Net is perfect for me but I can only get the cookie name and value from it.

Does anyone know of such browser engine that can do this work?
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember the HttpWebRequest can do the job for you:

```
                HttpWebRequest request =
               (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://your.site");
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                HttpWebResponse response = loginReq.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                CookieCollection cookies = response.Cookies;
```

The `cookies` will contain all the cookies from the site.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot use the HttpWebRequest, I must use a Web browser engine because I need the engine to return the page after executing all javascript codes. Any idea?